# Find sql records containing similar strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table with 2 columns: ID and Title containing over 500.000 records. For example:

```
ID  Title
--  ------------------------
1   Aliens
2   Aliens (1986)
3   Aliens vs Predator
4   Aliens 2
5   The making of "Aliens"
```

I need to find records that are very similar, and by that I mean they are different by 3-6 letters, usually this difference is at the end of the Titles. So I have to design a query that returns the records no. 1,2 and 4. I already looked at levenstein distance but I don't know how to apply it. Also because of the number of records the query shouldn't take all night long.

Thanks for any idea or suggestion

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I concur with Shekhar_Pro. (EDIT: but where did his comment go?): to exclude Aliens vs Predator, you have to be employing some non-explicit meta-data, such as, for example, that you want ONLY the film and any sequels, and you don't happen to consider Aliens vs Predator to be a sequel of Aliens. And that a 4-digit year in parentheses following the title should be ignored. When the title is evaluated simply as a string, the Predator film would be included, because the "v" of "vs" is no different than the "(" of (1986) or the "2" of Aliens 2.

Comment: @Andomar: it is sql server 2008

Comment: @Tim: I want to exclude Aliens vs Predator because after the word "Aliens" there are 12 charaters. And I want my limit to be, let's say 7 characters. More that this number and the strings will not be considered similar.  5 is excluded because it doesn't start with "Aliens". Thanks

Comment: A very basic algorythim from the point of view of a c# programmer would be: 1)For every record in db take the title(t1) 2) go through the rest of the records (tn) and compare t1 with tn. If tn has less than 7 characters after t1 than show it. Very rudimentary, I know, but I am a totally noob in sql and don't know how to tanspose that. Thank you a lot for your help

Comment: I have experience with de-duping titles and at the end, the fastest, most accurate way to do it is to have a human do it. For example, suppose one of the titles is *Alien 2* (with no trailing "s")? Take the Hellraiser franchise as an example of some of the problems you might encounter. You might have *Hellraiser 2*, *Hellraiser II*, *Hellbound: Hellraiser II*, *Hellraiser 2 Hellbound* and so on.

Comment: Another example using the Alien franchise, *Alien 4*, *Aliens 4*, *Alien: Resurrection*. While you might be able to use the Levenshtein distance to match the first two (although they would also match to *Alien 2* and *Aliens 2*), there is no way it would match against *Alien: Resurrection*.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you really want to define similarity in the exact way that you have formulated in your question, then you would - as you say - have to implement the Levensthein Distance calculation. Either in code calculated on each row retrieved by a DataReader or as a SQL Server function.

The problem stated is actually more tricky than it may appear at first sight, because you cannot assume to know what the *mutually shared* elements between two strings may be.

So in addition to Levensthein Distance you probably also want to specify a minimum number of consecutive characters that actually have to match (in order for sufficient similarity to be concluded).

In sum: It sounds like an overly complicated and time consuming/slow approach.

Interestingly, in SQL Server 2008 you have the [DIFFERENCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188753.aspx) function which *may* be used for something like this.

It evaluates the phonetic value of two strings and calculates the difference. I'm unsure if you will get it to work properly for multi-word expressions such as movie titles since it doesn't deal well with spaces or numbers and puts too much emphasis on the beginning of the string, but it is still an interesting predicate to be aware of.

If what you are *actually* trying to describe is some sort of search feature, then you should look into the [Full Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) capabilities of SQL Server 2008. It provides built-in [Thesaurus support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142491.aspx), fancy SQL [predicates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) and a ranking mechanism for "best matches"

EDIT: If you are looking to eliminate duplicates maybe you could look into SSIS [Fuzzy Lookup and Fuzzy Group Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nb-no/library/ms345128.aspx). I have not tried this myself, but it looks like a promising lead.

EDIT2: If you don't want to dig into SSIS and still struggle with the performance of the Levensthein Distance algorithm, you could perhaps try this [algorithm](http://sites.google.com/site/sqlblindman/fuzzysearchalgorithm) which appears to be less complex.

Comment: Have you ever actually used the `DIFFERENCE` function or `SOUNDEX`? Results are bizarre. Try `SELECT DIFFERENCE('The making of "Aliens"','Toy Story 2')`

Comment: @Simen: this is not a search feature. A client has a db with DVD titles and found out some of them are doubled. I raised some of the questions posted from you: @Thomas your scenario would be a nightmare :) but thanksfully this is not the case, an operator is entering the title and year( from the DVD cover in a string field(not a too good idea I believe) and they said it is unlikely to receive 2 DVDs of the same movie with different titles.

Comment: Also it seems the no 1 mistake is the year, when one person writes 2000, insead of 2001 and another one, receiving a new batch of DVDs inserts the same title but with the correct year. No 2 mistake is the wrong sequel number so it ends up with the same sequel(Alien 1 1979, Alien 1 1981 instead of being Alien 2). Misspeslling of the title was very rarely.They will do a manual search and replace but they don't want to go through the whole 500.000 unordered records. And a narrower list would help them. Right now I'm working on the 'You probably don't want to use this approach' of Simen

Comment: @Alex: A-ha. So you want a feature to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: So far I've done this: select distinct M.MovieId, M.MovieTitle
from Movie M
join Movie M2
on M2.MovieId>M.MovieId 
and dbo.Edit_Distance(M.MovieTitle,M2.MovieTitle)<3. Where the function Edit Distance is the Levensthein Distance. It returns satisfactory results altough it seems to take hours to complete. Any idea on optimisation? Thank you

Comment: @Alex: It probably takes a long time to complete because the Levensthein Distance algorithm is O(n-squared) and you're doing it for all the rows in your table.

Comment: I started work with your second link, that fuzzy search algorithm. It produces very similar results to Levensthein Distance but faster. Also using table variables to work only with some of the data increases time. Thanks

Comment: @MartinSmith, I believe Soundex and Difference are for comparing words and not sentences.

Comment: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-string-functions/sql-server-difference-function/  Difference does not compare two sentences for similarity.  Difference compares the difference of the soundex as a numerical value.  DIFFERENCE('Two', 'Too') similarity yields the value 4

Answer (score 5):

For all the Googlers out there that run into this question, though it's already been marked as answered, I figured I'd share some code to help with this.  If you're able to do CLR user-defined functions on your SQL Server, you can implement your own Levensthein Distance algorithm and then from there create a function that gives you a 'similarity score' called `dbo.GetSimilarityScore()`.  I've based my score case-insensitivity, without much weight to jumbled word order and non-alphanumeric characters.  You can adjust your scoring algorithm as needed, but this is a good start.  Credit to [this code project link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/improvestringsimilarity.aspx) for getting me started.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Compare Binary
Option Infer On

Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.SqlTypes
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Server

Partial Public Class UserDefinedFunctions

    Private Const Xms As RegexOptions = RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace Or RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.Singleline
    Private Const Xmsi As RegexOptions = Xms Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Compute the distance between two strings.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="s1">The first of the two strings.</param>
    ''' <param name="s2">The second of the two strings.</param>
    ''' <returns>The Levenshtein cost.</returns>
    <Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction()> _
    Public Shared Function ComputeLevenstheinDistance(ByVal string1 As SqlString, ByVal string2 As SqlString) As SqlInt32
        If string1.IsNull OrElse string2.IsNull Then Return SqlInt32.Null
        Dim s1 As String = string1.Value
        Dim s2 As String = string2.Value

        Dim n As Integer = s1.Length
        Dim m As Integer = s2.Length
        Dim d As Integer(,) = New Integer(n, m) {}

        ' Step 1
        If n = 0 Then Return m
        If m = 0 Then Return n

        ' Step 2
        For i As Integer = 0 To n
            d(i, 0) = i
        Next

        For j As Integer = 0 To m
            d(0, j) = j
        Next

        ' Step 3
        For i As Integer = 1 To n
            'Step 4
            For j As Integer = 1 To m
                ' Step 5
                Dim cost As Integer = If((s2(j - 1) = s1(i - 1)), 0, 1)

                ' Step 6
                d(i, j) = Math.Min(Math.Min(d(i - 1, j) + 1, d(i, j - 1) + 1), d(i - 1, j - 1) + cost)
            Next
        Next
        ' Step 7
        Return d(n, m)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns a score between 0.0-1.0 indicating how closely two strings match.  1.0 is a 100%
    ''' T-SQL equality match, and the score goes down from there towards 0.0 for less similar strings.
    ''' </summary>
    <Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction()> _
    Public Shared Function GetSimilarityScore(string1 As SqlString, string2 As SqlString) As SqlDouble
        If string1.IsNull OrElse string2.IsNull Then Return SqlInt32.Null

        Dim s1 As String = string1.Value.ToUpper().TrimEnd(" "c)
        Dim s2 As String = string2.Value.ToUpper().TrimEnd(" "c)
        If s1 = s2 Then Return 1.0F ' At this point, T-SQL would consider them the same, so I will too

        Dim score1 As SqlDouble = InternalGetSimilarityScore(s1, s2)
        If score1.IsNull Then Return SqlDouble.Null

        Dim mod1 As String = GetSimilarityString(s1)
        Dim mod2 As String = GetSimilarityString(s2)
        Dim score2 As SqlDouble = InternalGetSimilarityScore(mod1, mod2)
        If score2.IsNull Then Return SqlDouble.Null

        If score1 = 1.0F AndAlso score2 = 1.0F Then Return 1.0F
        If score1 = 0.0F AndAlso score2 = 0.0F Then Return 0.0F
        ' Return weighted result
        Return (score1 * 0.2F) + (score2 * 0.8F)
    End Function

    Private Shared Function InternalGetSimilarityScore(s1 As String, s2 As String) As SqlDouble
        Dim dist As SqlInt32 = ComputeLevenstheinDistance(s1, s2)
        Dim maxLen As Integer = If(s1.Length > s2.Length, s1.Length, s2.Length)
        If maxLen = 0 Then Return 1.0F
        Return 1.0F - Convert.ToDouble(dist.Value) / Convert.ToDouble(maxLen)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Removes all non-alpha numeric characters and then sorts
    ''' the words in alphabetical order.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Shared Function GetSimilarityString(s1 As String) As String
        Dim normString = Regex.Replace(If(s1, ""), "\W|_", " ", Xms)
        normString = Regex.Replace(normString, "\s+", " ", Xms).Trim()
        Dim words As New List(Of String)(normString.Split(" "c))
        words.Sort()
        Return String.Join(" ", words.ToArray())
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: I've been found if there are large number of records then it takes more and more time. I exercised with 40K and it took 10-15 mins. Can you please suggest me any alternative for this?

Answer (score 3):

```
select id, title
from my_table
where 
    title like 'Aliens%' 
    and 
    len(rtrim(title)) < len('Aliens') + 7
```

Answer (score 1):

From what you've asked I imagine the differences you're looking for should not be more than a single word at the end of the original title. Is that why 1,2 and 4 are returned?

Anyway I've made a query that checks the difference at the end consists of a single word, without spaces.

```
declare @title varchar(20)
set @title = 'Aliens'
select id, title
from movies with (nolock)
where ltrim(title) like @title + '%'
and Charindex(' ', ltrim(right(title, len(title) - len(@title)))) = 0
and len(ltrim(right(title, len(title) - len(@title)))) < 7
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using sql server 2008 you should be able to use the FULLTEXT functionality.

The basic steps are:

1) Create a fulltext index over the column. This will tokenise each string (stremmers, splitters, etc) and let you search for 'LIKE THIS' strings.

The disclaimer is that I've never had to use it but I think it can do what you want.

Start reading here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try SSIS Fuzzy Grouping and it will give you score based on string matches.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

You can also use utl_match in Oracle.
[enter link description here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/utl_match-string-matching-in-oracle)

Comment: Please add more details regardless of the link you mentioned