# Can MSSQL Full Text find document similarities?

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I am looking for a means to relate/find similarities in MSSSQL full text documents to themselves in the same table/column or separately to documents in a different table. I already have the table full text indexed but now need to understand how I might go about finding the documents that are similar. Consider the following example:

I have a ticketing system that stores customer issues:

TicketID    TextColumn

1234    My computer has a virus.

1235    My mouse is broken.

1236    There is a virus in my computer

As a new ticket is filed, I want to use the TicketID number say 1236 which I could pass into a stored procedure and see which of the other documents in the table are similar and return them in some sort of ranking order based on highest similarity. So in this case 1236 more closely matches 1234.

All I am finding in my research is the ability to search on specific words or phrases, but I want to pass in the entire document's contents. Does anyone know the method to do this?

Comment: I've never used it myself, but [Semantic Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492075.aspx) in SQL 2012 appears to do what you want. If upgrading isn't an option, then you will have to come up with something yourself: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299996/find-sql-records-containing-similar-strings) has some relevant discussion and [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) is often mentioned as a possible alternative to using SQL Server's own FTS features.