# Entity framework find similar string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, search

Is there a way how to find similar string in database via EF?
I would like to show users already existing questionts when he tries to add a new one (Implementation of exactly same feature as here on stack overflow "Questions that may already have your answer").
And order them by relevancy

Answer (score 1):

well you can execute any arbitary sql and get entity framework object back.

```
using (var context = new myContext()) 
{ 
    var myObject= context.myObject.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.myObject where 'super duper where statement'").ToList(); 
}
```

And you can use full text search and all sorts of strange mechanisms in your sql statements.

look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299996/find-sql-records-containing-similar-strings) for further info

Answer (score 0):

I believe stackoverflow is currently using the popular [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) engine to index the entries and provide this functionality and it would be pretty cumbersome to try and implement this using only EF (if at all possible). However you still can use the normal string methods (StartsWith, Contains, etc) for providing some somewhat complex search functionality other than the simple matching of strings. For example:

```
var searchResult = Context.Products.All(x => x.Name.Contains("searchTerm"));
```